# Remove word with regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have an array

```
["killed", "thanks", "thank","+", "?", "]", "[", "(", ")", "*"]
```

I want to remove some strings from a text if they are included in the array.

With this example, I want to remove "beauty", but not "beautifully". How can I do that?

I tried using regex:

```
text = "thanks john, Have you ever killed someone ?"
arry_words = ["killed", "thanks", "+", "?", "]", "[", "(", ")", "*"]
text.downcase.gsub(Regexp.new("\\b+(?:#{arry_words.join('|')})\\b"), '').strip
```

but I get some errors like:

- `RegexpError: target of repeat operator is not specified`
- `RegexpError: end pattern with unmatched parenthesis: ...`

Comment: Not directly pertinent to your question but relevant: Your idea of using word boundary anchors is commendable but only works with actual words.  Regexes like `\b+\b` will only match if the plus is surrounded by word characters.

Comment: >> With this example, I want to remove "beauty", but not "beautifully". << I don't see those words in your array, or anywhere else in the question.  I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @Wayne, bad example, methinks. I expect the meaning is remove `"beau"` but not `"beauty"`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think it is indeed a bad example.  It makes the question unclear to me.  I hope the OP can improve it.

Comment: Note that removing characters isn't the same as removing "words", in the sense that people can still include text that doesn't obey your rules but can be comprehensible to a human reader. For expmale, I can wirte smoe vrey misepeled wrods and I bet you can skill reed thum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The search words you have contain special regex metacharacters that should be escaped before using them in the regex pattern. This can be achieve easily with [`Regexp.union`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Regexp.html#method-c-union) that actually both *joins* with `|` and *escapes* the special characters.

> Return a Regexp object that is the union of the given *patterns*, i.e., will match any of its parts. The *patterns* can be Regexp objects, in which case their options will be preserved, or Strings.

Another problem is that `\b` word boundary is context-dependent, if placed before a non-word char, it requires a word char before that character, and if placed after a non-word char, it requires a word char after that non-word char.

Use

```
text.downcase.gsub(/(?<!\w)(?:#{Regexp.union(arry_words)})(?!\w)/, '').strip
```

See [this Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/68QBkF).

The `(?<!\w)` will make sure the search word is not preceded with a word char, and `(?!\w)` will make sure the search word is not followed with a word char.

***Note*** that in this case, all the punctuation symbols won't match in case they are glued to word chars.

If you still need to use `\b` as word boundary, you need to analyze the search word array first, and add `\b` wherever search word starts/ends with a word char. Something like

```
arry_words = arry_words.map { |x| 
    if x =~ /\A\w.*\w\z/ 
        x = "\\b#{Regexp.escape(x)}\\b"
    elsif x =~ /\A\w/ 
        x = "\\b" + Regexp.escape(x)
    elsif x =~ /\w\z/ 
        x = Regexp.escape(x) + "\\b"
    else
        x = Regexp.escape(x)
    end
}
rx = Regexp.new(arry_words.join('|'))
text.downcase.gsub(rx, '').strip
```

See [this Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/1k63E4).

Comment: If you add `"_"` to `arry_words` and `text = "thanks john, Have you ever killed some_one?"` then your code returns `"john, have you ever  some_one"`. That is of course because `"_".match? /\w/ #=> true`.  If you replace `\w` everywhere with `[[:alnum]]` you get the desired behaviour. That's one of the reasons I rarely use `\w`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Different applications require different definitions of a "word" and thus a "word boundary". I rarely need `\b`, I use lookarounds more often than `\b`. Say, to match a string of digits I'd use `(?<!\d)\d+(?!\d)`, to match a whole "linguistic" word, I'd use `(?<!\p{L})\p{L}+(?!\p{L})`. BTW, that is why I put it as *If you still need to use \b as word boundary*. And since `\b` is "tied" to `\w` and `\W` meanings, the code looks as it does.

Comment: Interesting points. It didn't occur to me you can't mix and match `\b` with the `\p{..}` construct or POSIX expressions, but that should have been obvious. If the underscore is important in the expression (and the expression is in English), `\b` and `\w` are useful; otherwise, the inclusion of an underscore as a word character seems only to complicate things and have the potential for creating bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
regexp = Regexp.union(words)
```

Or this with word boundaries

```
regexp = /\b(#{Regexp.union(words).source})\b/i
```

`Regexp#union` escapes special characters in strings and will thus avoid the errors that you're getting.

Comment: You may need to frame this with `\b` if you want to only match words on boundaries, not take out things like partial words.

Comment: @tadman: Not as simple as that since some of the search terms aren't words.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Yeah, this one's got some very *peculiar* words.

Comment: Good catch, added variant with word boundaries and ignore case. Assuming they included non-words like `+` as an illustration of the need for escaping only.

Comment: Just to make it clearer, you could mention that Regexp.union escapes elements in `words`.

Comment: I doubt that the OP wants `"(egad!)" =~ regexp #=> nil`. I expect inclusion of word boundaries depends on the context.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in two steps. Doing so removes the need to escape certain characters and to have the inclusion of word boundaries depend on where they are placed.

```
arry_words = ["kissed", "kill", "+", "?", "]", "[", "(", ")", "*"]

word_words = arry_words.select { |w| w =~ /\A[[:alpha:]]+\z/ }
  #=> ["kissed", "kill"]

r = /\b#{Regexp.union(word_words)}\b/i
  #=> /\b(?-mix:kissed|kill)\b/i

text = "Thanks John, have you (ever) kissed and killed so[me**one?"

text.delete((arry_words-word_words).join).gsub(r, '')
  #=> "Thanks John, have you ever  or killed someone"
```

Note

```
text.delete((arry_words-word_words).join)
  #=> "Thanks John, have you ever kissed and killed someone"
```